# floor & ceil for positive floating point values

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a **positive** (including zero) floating point number, for which I am interested to have the previous and next representable integers, on that floating point scale `F`.

Is `floor(x)` and `ceil(x)` are the idiomatic way of calculating them, or `trunc(x)`, `trunc(x+1)`? How can I modify them, when I **know** that those integers can be represented by some integer scale `I` (i.e will `static_cast` work, or I need to have functions like `ltrunc` etc which I do not understand completely) . I am also interested to know about performance of them.

Comment: Regarding performance, it really depends on the precise instruction set you are targeting. See the history of `FISTP` and `FISTTP` for the x87 as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

floor and ceil are fine.

Please be aware

```
floor(1) == ceil(1)
```

and

```
trunc(1) != trunc(1+1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I completely missed that point! Is `ceil(x)` equivalent to `trunc(nexttoward(x + 1, x))` for positive x ?

Comment: @abir No. Try your formula with `4503599627370495.5`